# return random models in json format - django

Tags: json, python-3.x, django

I need to return random data from models in json format but when I try `random.choice` I got the error `'Joke' object is not iterable` .

views.py

```
def random_page(request):
   random_joke = random.choice(Joke.objects.all())

   jokes_list = serializers.serialize('json', random_joke)
   return HttpResponse(jokes_list, content_type="text/json-comment-filtered")
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Joke(models.Model):
    joke = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.joke)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acutally the issue is `serializers.serialize` expects an iterable i.e object that can be iterated. You are passing single object which is not iterable. So better to add the object in iterable like `list`

```
jokes_list = serializers.serialize('json', [random_joke])
```

Comment: Np. Title should be like serializing random object of queryset.